# Are two standard normal distributions dependent? Why?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

$X \sim N(0, 1)$ and $Y \sim N(0, 1)$

Are $X$ and $Y$ dependent? How can you mathematically show that?

I understand that $X$ and $Y$ are defined as the exact same standard normal distribution, but still I am a little bit confused when it comes to proving dependence in a continuous setting.  Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of (in)dependent?

Comment: My definition of independence is that the probability that two events occur is equal to the probability of that the first one occurs, multiplied by the second.

Comment: That's independence of events. What's your definition of independence of variables?

Comment: I think if the joint PDF is equal the multiplication of both PDFs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The marginal distributions alone do not tell you anything about how $X$ and $Y$ are related, and if they are independent or not. For that you need more information, for example their joint pdf (often denoted $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$) or some knowledge of what the random variables represent.

To give an extreme case, assume $X=Y$, which obviously means they have the same distribution. In this case, they are perfectly dependent: Knowing the value of $X$ immediately tells you the value of $Y$. On the other hand, there are many situations where some random variables $X$ and $Y$ happen to have the same distribution, but in fact they measure completely different things, such that they are independent.

Comment: Ohhhh this makes sense thank you. For example, if $Z = AX$ where $A$ is Rademacher distribution and $X$ is a standard normal distribution, $Z$ and $X$ both share the same standard normal distribution but measure totally different things like you've said correct?

Comment: Yes, to formally prove independence you need to show that the joint pdf can be written as the product of the two marginal pdfs (also works with cdfs).